# "Unexpected token in JSON at position 0"?

Tags: json, node.js, angular

I'm writing a node.js module which imports a JSON file:

```
const distDirPath = "c:/temp/dist/";
const targetPagePath = "c:/temp/index.html";
const cliJsonPath = "C:/CODE/MyApp/.angular-cli.json";
const fs = require('fs');

function deployAot()
{
    var version = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(cliJsonPath, 'utf8')).version;
}

// export the module
module.exports = {
    DeployAot: deployAot
};
```

I validated the contents of the json file above in https://jsonlint.com/ and it's valid json but the first line of code above in deployAot() returns the following error when I exec the node module:

```
"Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0"
```

Here's the specific json:

https://jsonblob.com/cd6753d2-9e51-11e7-aa97-2f95b001b178

Any idea what the problem might be here?

Comment: Maybe show us a JSON itself?

Comment: Byte order mark?

Comment: Try to simplify your JSON to 1 key-value pair. Then print result of `fs.readFileSync(cliJsonPath, 'utf8')` and see if there are any strange character at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @LEQADA I updated my original post with a url to the json

Comment: this probably doesn't help with your error, but a future one. shouldn't it be `var version = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(cliJsonPath, 'utf8')).project.version;` ?

Comment: I would debug by seeing if its a valid file first by printing out `fs.lstatSync(cliJsonPath).isFile()` if its not then you know your file path needs work like try replacing / with \

Comment: @AndrewLohr why not use var?  var works with my broader implementation if I hard-code the value

Comment: I was talking about you missing `project` key after the parse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @cartant already mentioned in comments to the question, most probably you get a special character (Byte order mark) at the beginning of the file.

I would try to replace this

```
fs.readFileSync(cliJsonPath, 'utf8')
```

with this

```
fs.readFileSync(cliJsonPath, 'utf8').substring(1)
```

to get rid of the very first character from the string and would see what happens.

---

GitHub issue [fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8') doesn't strip BOM markers](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1918)

Recommendation from the issue:

> Workaround:
>
> `body = body.replace(/^\uFEFF/, '');`
>
> After reading a UTF8 file where you are uncertain whether it may have a BOM marker in it.

Comment: substring(1) is the fix!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - the file starts with "{" when opened in Visual Studio.  Not sure where the magic first character comes from.or how to get rid of it

Comment: @user8570495 I think you will see that magic special character if you will open your file in some hex editor